# If you change a user's redshift password, will any pre-existing connections for that user remain valid?

Tags: passwords, credentials, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have a Redshift user `'person1`' with password `'oldpassword'`, and I have a few existing open Redshift connections using these credentials. I then run the following command:

```
alter user person1 password 'newpassword'
```

For any new connections, I will of course have to use the new credentials `'person1'` and `'newpassword'`. But will the already existing connections remain valid, or will they suddenly stop working after this command?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7):

Changing the password will not immediately terminate ongoing connections. The superuser can manually do that with [PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/PG_TERMINATE_BACKEND.html), if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you change the password of a user, you cannot execute any statement in any session in workbench that was already connected before password change.

Note: Aren't "Existing connections" are also any open tabs in a sql/aginity workbench? You won't be able to execute any new query in those already open tabs. Probably the OP meant "ongoing" connections on the database side.

Comment: While I am slowly trying to reach towards 50 reps to be able to comment and ask queries on my favorite questions, these "downvotes" really don't help.